# Convert string array from JSON sublist

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, using

I have sublist in my JSON response, as

```
"sublist" : {
    "102" : "Core_Java(23)",
    "103" : "Oracle(12)",
    "111" : "Ruchek(15)",
    "104" : "IST-Examportal(20)",
    "105" : "CyberSecurity(30)"
}
```

I want to make it like this

```
var jsonSource = '[{
        "ID" : 102,
        "SUBNAME" : "Core_Java(23)"
    }, {
        "ID" : 103,
        "SUBNAME" : "Oracle(12)"
    }, {
        "ID" : 111,
        "SUBNAME" : "Ruchek(15)"
    }, {
        "ID" : 104,
        "SUBNAME" : "IST-Examportal(20)"
    }, {
        "ID" : 105,
        "SUBNAME" : "CyberSecurity(30)"
    }
]';
```

Help me to do this using JavaScript.

Comment: So what have you tried and where are you stuck? This looks like a simple application of `map()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a for-in loop.

```
var result = [];

for(var property in sublist){
   if(sublist.hasOwnProperty(property)){
      result.push({ID: property, SUBNAME: sublist[property]});
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `for..in` loop:

```
var sublist = [],
    jsonSource;

for (var key in obj.sublist) {
    sublist.push({
        "ID" : key,
        "SUBNAME" : obj.sublist[key]
    });
}

jsonSource = JSON.stringify(sublist);
```